# How to use Moya to download file

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

Usual I use `Alamofire` & `Moya/RxSwift` & `ObjectMapper` to analysis object
But now add a demand. My app need download file.

I have use

```
Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination)
```

Temporary solved the problem

but It's not elegant.

I want use Moya to Maintain the same network layer.

Can you show a Download Moya"s "TargetType"

Answer (score 2):

to use Moya to download files, the key thing is override 
`

```
var task:Task{
    switch self {
        case .download:
        return .download(DownloadType.request(DefaultDownloadDestination))
   }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/pandaApe/fac2615f729c9a0cf6bab29700416747

Answer (score 1):

@Tony, you have two options according current Moya API.

```
/// A file download task to a destination.
case downloadDestination(DownloadDestination)

/// A file download task to a destination with extra parameters using the given encoding.
case downloadParameters(parameters: [String: Any], encoding: ParameterEncoding, destination: DownloadDestination)
```

Answer (score 0):

try wit this code to use custom path to save the file

```
var task: Task {
    switch self {
    case .getFile(let request):
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let devFolderUrl = documentsDirectory[0].appendingPathComponent("\yourfolder")
        let fileUrl = devFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("\filename.ext")
        var downloadDest: DownloadDestination {
            return { _, _ in return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories]) }
        }
        
        return .downloadDestination(downloadDest)
    }
}
```